# Order By nHibernate Causes 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException'

Tags: c#, linq, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I get the following error

> Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown.
>   [.OrderBy[ORM.Entities.Core.Message,System.DateTime](.Where[ORM.Entities.Core.Message](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[ORM.Entities.Core.Message],
>   Quote((x, ) =>
>   (AndAlso(AndAlso(String.op_Equality(x.ConcerningItemType, p1),
>   Equal(x.ConcerningItemId, p2)), OrElse(Equal(x.Sender.Id, p3),
>   .Any[ORM.Entities.Core.MessageRecipient](x.Recipients, (r, ) =>
>   (Equal(r.Employee.Id, p4)), ))))), ), Quote((x, ) =>
>   (.FirstORM.Entities.Core.AuditGroup.Created)), )]

When I have a IQueryable result set (having just applied some logic to it) and then I try to order it by a child properties variable before calling ToList()

```
var results = query.Where(x => x.ConcerningItemType == "1422" && x.ConcerningItemId == EnquiryId && //Messages for this Enquiry
                            (x.Sender.Id == EmployeeId || x.Recipients.Any(r => r.Employee.Id == EmployeeId)));
```

Then I try to order which causes a error

```
var results2 = results.OrderBy(x => x.AuditGroup.First().Created).ToList();
```

If I do the following instead I don't get a error (move the tolist to force it to hit the database)

```
var results3 = results.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.AuditGroup.First().Created);
```

---

Ask requested more information

AuditGroup Class

```
    public class AuditGroup : Entity
{
    public virtual string Guid { get; set; }
    public virtual string PageName { get; set; }
    public virtual string ControlId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ItemType { get; set; }
    public virtual int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string Parameters { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }

}
```

Message Class

```
    public class Message : Entity
{
    // This class represents the standard address fields, for reuse in other entities
    // 
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int ConcerningItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual String ConcerningItemType { get; set; }
    public virtual String Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual String Body { get; set; }
    public virtual int RecipientCount { get; set; }
    public virtual String RowStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Sender { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MessageRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }

    //eww have to do this to be able to access the created date of the message (stored in AuditGroup... Stupidly!)
    public virtual ICollection<AuditGroup> AuditGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Messages Mapping

```
        public MessageMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("MessageId");
        Map(x => x.ConcerningItemId).Nullable().Column("ItemId");
        Map(x => x.ConcerningItemType).Nullable().Column("ItemType");

        Map(x => x.Subject).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Body);
        Map(x => x.RecipientCount).Column("MessageRecipientCount");
        Map(x => x.RowStatus).Column("MessageRowStatus");

        References(x => x.Sender).Column("EmployeeId");
        HasMany(x => x.Recipients).KeyColumn("MessageId");

        //AuditGroup has ItemId-ItemType Needs to map to MessageId-ItemType
        HasMany(x => x.AuditGroup).KeyColumn("ItemId").Where("ItemType = '1419'");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please provide more info (Entities and Maps)

I am pretty sure `x.AuditGroup.First().Created` is to blame. I say this because I try to think the SQL query generated and I can't.

I suggest creating an Alias for `AuditGroup` and ordering with that. This is very roughly how I would do it.

```
AuditGroup auditGroupAlias = null;

query.JoinAlias(p => p.AuditGroup, () => auditGroupAlias)
     .OrderBy(()=>auditGroupAlias.Created)
```

Again with partial information I can give only a partial solution.

Comment: as requested I have provided mapping class and the two entity classes

Comment: why would I need to create a alias when messages knows of its collection of auditgroups already?

Comment: because you can't do `First()` inside the `OrderBy` or so I know

Comment: Also in the few tests I run I get an exception when doing it (though not the same one as you)